# Table View Cell separator line invisible from farther away

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I am working with a table view with custom cells which are all xib's. On a normal iOS device and when the zoom is set to a normal distance, the separator line is invisible. If, on the emulator, I zoom in on the device, I am able to see the separator line. How could I fix this issue? Attached are the two images of the emulator (one with a bigger zoom than the other).

Thanks!

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this you must run it at **100% scale** (Cmd + 1) , or **interact with it** (drag to scroll), or **run it on a real device**. There are no other workarounds.

It happens because when you zoom in it must shrink the pixels to fit everything into the screen. The best thing to do is to run it on a real device if you want to take screen shots or present the app.